# How can i auto click a notification in ubuntu 20.10 with gnome

Tags: gnome, notification

Hello i have a program that sends a notification after a certain amount of time( 10 to 20 secs). With notify-send. and the notification appears near my clock. what i want to do is i would like to autoclick it whenever it pops up. Is there a way to automate this process? i checked online but with no sccess. Please help will be appreciated